# How to clip the container with half circle outward in bottom center

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-layout

I have this design which i want to create

[image: Bottom button image]

I have tried this code :

```
@override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();

    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height - 50);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2 - 35 , size.height -50);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2 - 35 , size.height , size.width / 2 + 120 , size.height);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width /2 + 35 , size.height, size.width / 2 + 35, size.height - 50);

    path.lineTo(size.width / 2 + size.width, size.height - 50);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);

    path.close();
    return path;


  }
```

But i am failing to do ... The result i am getting is

[image: My result]

I can't understand what i am doing wrong. Pleas help me also i want that shadow as well after clipping at the bottom. but i am not getting that to make things visible i change the colour of scaffold to grey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing with the height and adding shadow to clip path i finally get close to desire result.

```
var path = Path();

path.lineTo(0.0, size.height - 50);
path.lineTo(size.width / 2 - 35 , size.height -50);

path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2 - 35 , size.height - 25 , size.width / 2 , size.height -20);

path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width /2 + 35 , size.height -25 , size.width / 2 + 35, size.height - 50);

path.lineTo(size.width / 2 + size.width, size.height - 50);
path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);

path.close();
return path;
```

The image container now looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you really only need to draw one curve and not two.

```
Path getClip(Size size) {
    final Path path = Path()
      ..lineTo(0, size.height - 35)
      ..lineTo((size.width / 2) - 50, size.height - 35)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, size.height + 35, (size.width / 2) + 50, size.height - 35,)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height - 35)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
      ..close();

    return path;
  }
```